# Call to a member function getEmbedHtml() on a non-object

Tags: cakephp, vimeo

I am integrating Vimeo Player with my cakephp application and its giving me the above error

```
 Error: Call to a member function getEmbedHtml() on a non-object
 File: C:\wamp\www\ann\app\View\Videos\index.ctp
 Line: 1
```

and here is my line 1

```
  <?php echo $vimeo->getEmbedHtml('https://www.vimeo.com/44633289', array()); ?>
```

This link is working https://www.vimeo.com/44633289

Here is the `Vimeohelper.php` file

```
<?php 
class VimeoHelper extends AppHelper 
{ 
    /** 
     * Creates Vimeo Embed Code from a given Vimeo Video. 
     * 
     *    @param String $vimeo_id URL or ID of Video on Vimeo.com 
     *    @param Array $usr_options VimeoHelper Options Array (see below) 
     *    @return String HTML output. 
    */ 
    function getEmbedCode($vimeo_id, $usr_options = array()) 
    { 
        // Default options. 
        $options = array 
        ( 
            'width' => 400, 
            'height' => 225, 
            'show_title' => 1, 
            'show_byline' => 1, 
            'show_portrait' => 0, 
            'color' => '00adef', 
        ); 
        $options = array_merge($options, $usr_options); 

        // Extract Vimeo.id from URL. 
        if (substr($vimeo_id, 0, 21) == 'http://www.vimeo.com/') { 
            $vimeo_id = substr($vimeo_id, 21); 
        } 

        $output = array(); 
        $output[] = sprintf('<object width="%s" height="%s">', $options['width'], $options['height']); 
        $output[] = ' <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />'; 
        $output[] =    ' <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />'; 
        $output[] =    sprintf(' <param name="movie" value="http://www.vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=%s&server=www.vimeo.com&show_title=%s&show_byline=%s&show_portrait=%s&color=%s&fullscreen=1" />', $vimeo_id, $options['show_title'], $options['show_byline'], $options['show_portrait'], $options['color']);
        $output[] = sprintf(' <embed src="http://www.vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=%s&server=www.vimeo.com&show_title=%s&show_byline=%s&show_portrait=%s&color=%s&fullscreen=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="%s" height="%s"></embed>', $vimeo_id, $options['show_title'], $options['show_byline'], $options['show_portrait'], $options['color'], $options['width'], $options['height']);
        $output[] = '</object>'; 

        return $this->output(implode($output, "\n")); 
    } 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you everything you need to know.
You are not properly accessing the helper.

a) you need to include it in your controllers `public $helpers`

b) you need to call it properly using `$this-Vimeo` and the correct method name (you cannot just invent your own name since the method needs to exist!):

```
<?php echo $this-Vimeo->getEmbedCode(...); ?>
```

Your code snippet with `$vimeo->` would be correct for the totally outdated cake1.2 (not for cake1.3 or cake2.x).

Comment: public $helpers = array('Vimeo');   used in controller
<?php echo $this->Vimeo->getEmbedHtml('https://www.vimeo.com/44633289', array()); ?> in index.ctp


and now its giving me warning

Warning (512): Method VimeoHelper::getEmbedHtml does not exist [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 191]

Comment: Why are you inventing method names here? Your helper clearly states the method is called `getEmbedCode()`.

Comment: Hi thanks it worked but still video is not showing instead outer part is displaying with inside message

Sorry This video does not exist

Comment: In the end nothing helps against crappy helper code. The code might also be outdated.

Comment: is there any other way to implement vimeo in cakephp dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more info about how you initialize $vimeo?

Most likely $vimeo is initialized improperly and is set to null when you're accessing it here.
Hope this helps with your debugging.

Also it looks like getEmbedCode function in VimeoHelper is what you want to use instead of getEmbedHtml.

Consider changing the function definition to be

```
static function getEmbedCode($vimeo_id, $usr_options = array())
```

then you can get the embedded url later by calling:

```
VimeoHelper::getEmbedCode('https://www.vimeo.com/44633289', array())
```

Comment: I have added the Vimeohelper.php in the above section of question please check.

Comment: Vimeohelper.php doesn't contain the code which initializes the $vimeo variable from the first example.